# Xcode 11 SPM authentication failed because no credentials provided

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, swift-package-manager

I started using Swift package manager and when I add repository with https (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git) address authentication always fails when I try to login with my github account

[Xcode authentication fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLUqH.png)

But if I'm using git@github.com:Alamofire/Alamofire.git it will get added successfully. I tried regenerating new key, deleted .ssh directory but nothing makes https work and I still get xcode authentication failed because no credentials were provided error. I could use locally ssh url but in CI I need one with https.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

It was a problem with git config. In .gitconfig file it was set to

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

After removing this section https worked correctly

EDIT: as mentioned in comments you can easily access your gitconfig in terminal with command: `git config --global --edit`

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me as well, thank you. One question I have is when/how did this get inserted into the .gitconfig file, or when/how did Xcode start choking on it? Because I have not changed it and starting with Xcode 11 GM, it broke all my builds that were using SPM.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. Somehow it got inserted... I found this solution by pure luck. Before I tried to completely reinstall XCode, created a new github account and other things.

Comment: In my case, it was inserted automatically by go because of https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https

Comment: I had the same issue. I put the force ssh in my `~/.gitconfig` intentionally because I have 2 factor authentication enabled with GitHub. However, there seems to be bugs in Xcode swift package manager, and you need to remove the line to force ssh.

Comment: I removed it, cleared Xcode's Github account, and then I was able to get another authentication login when I re-opened the Package.swift file. Before it was stuck downloading Swift-NIO and then all my targets would disappear.

Comment: To then who are searching git config file. To locate the .gitconfig file Only write this instruction on terminal:

git config --global --edit

Comment: This is a bug in XCode or the swift package manager in my opinion. It should respect your git config.

Comment: The bug in Xcode is really stupid, it doesn't respect the git config global stuff

Comment: I made this change yesterday because I wanted to switch to the SSH way as I find tokens not that feasible so I referred to [this](https://gist.github.com/m14t/3056747) and this morning I ran into this issue on Xcode

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: Had same issue on Xcode 12.4 and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: Helped with 13.3 as well, thanks!

Comment: I personally like keeping this settings, so what I did was to limit it to repos in my `~/Developer` directory using `[includeIf "gitdir:~/Developer/**"]`.

Comment: To delete this, in the command line run: `git config --global --unset-all url.git@github.com:.insteadof`

Comment: Same issue with Xcode 15  - even tho personal access tokens were valid, still had the error ---- THIS IS THE FIX.

Answer (score 19):

In my case with Xcode 11.3.1 I had the same problem and I solved changing de auth method to SSH from HTTPS in Github account preferences on Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

what worked for me was both [@SimonasDaniliauskas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58179025/4833705) and [@Abrahanfer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60633967/4833705)

Basically in the command line I had to run:

```
git config --global --unset-all url.git@github.com:.insteadof
```

And in Xcode I had to go to `Xcode` > `Preferences` and switch my GitHub to use `SSH`

Btw, if you don't have ssh setup, follow this [medium post](https://medium.com/make-school/a-noob-s-guide-f20b3db28011) or these [GitHub directions](https://gist.github.com/brennanMKE/8e09593ca4064deab59da807077d8f53). If you need to change your ssh keys follow this [YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/1YV9LoaNHf4)

Answer (score 10):

Building off of two previous answers, I solved this by doing what Abrahanfer did, setting `Clone using` to `SSH` in `Xcode Preferences -> Account`.

Then I used the SSH url of the repo, for example: `git@github.com:AppPear/SwiftUI-PullToRefresh.git`

Comment: This is correct, if you want to find the SSH url for the repo on github, press "Use SSH" in the top right corner (after you press the "clone or download" button)

Answer (score 7):

you can use ssh URLs instead of https, e.g. `git@github.com:ORG_NAME/REPO_NAME.git`

Comment: that helped me 

Answer (score 4):

I double clicked the error message `Error while fetching remote repository: git@github.com:ORG/REPO-NAME.git` or the `The server SSH fingerprint failed to verify`
in Xcode's Report Navigator which then a popup appeared asking if I wanted to trust the host. After clicking that I was able to add the Swift Package using SSH.

Selecting HTTPS or SSH in the Xcode Preferences did not fix for me because Xcode seems to automatically handle SSH GitHub URLs in the SPM flow.

Answer (score 2):

If you are facing this and your `.gitconfig` has below, **and you want to keep it!**

```
[url "git@github.com:"]
  insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

just add below two lines after above two lines in your `.gitconfig`

```
[url "https://github.com/apple"]
  insteadOf = https://github.com/apple
```

Duplicate above two lines and replace `/apple` with any other `/user` or `/org` where you might want to download your packages from

Answer (score 0):

Try removing it and adding it again. If that won't work, remove your GitHub account from Xcode. Usually, git via ssh works better. What CI are you using?

Comment: If I remove and try to add it again I get `xcode authentication failed because no credentials were provided error` when i login with my github account, I tried removing it and adding it again but it still doesn't work. I'm using Github Actions.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it seems more like a red herring (maybe a fellow developer accidentally checked in this small change related to swift package in project setting). I went to project setting, removed it from under "Swift Packages". It seems okay after that.

Answer (score 0):

I keep having this issue in Xcode 12.0.1 (12A7300).

My GitHub credentials seemed to not work, even though I applied all the suggestions above.

The way I fixed it (for now, at least) was to **switch to SSH only authentication**.

Comment: Where is that setting?

Comment: @TommySadiqHinrichsen unfortunately, it was not a setting per se, but a dialog that appeared when double-clicking on a failed authentication error from the logs in the Report navigator. It would ask me how to authenticate with GitHub and there was an option for SSH only. **After upgrading to Xcode 12.5.1, I haven't experienced the issue anymore**.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get HTTPS working fine with CI. The solution, with **bitrise**, is to use 'Authenticate host with netrc', then Xcode will find private HTTPS repos properly. I am sure other CI platforms (or your own) can setup the same solution.

Answer (score 0):

Adding repo via source tree and checking out repo through Xcode use some other tool, then adding same repo via SPM. Try creating SSH key via `rsa` key algorithm instead of `ed255189` key algorithm. SPM tool comfortably work with `rsa`.
Note: `rsa` key authentication is slower than `ed25519` key authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the other anwsers here with no success. Eventually it turned out that the package was added to XCode with my username inside the https domain, like that:

```
https://yarden_k@bitbucket.org/private/package/path.git
```

so I had to adjust the accepted answer the same way (I added those lines to .gitconfig file):

```
[url "git@bitbucket.org:"]
    insteadOf = https://yarden_k@bitbucket.org/
```

And viola! It finally worked. Was a real headache to figure this one out.

Answer (score -3):

Me too facing this problem

Check your repo access is correct and you have proper access for PUSH the code

They only gave me READ access, After facing this issue I'll informed to respective person and get WRITE access